# Distribution probabilities for each column data frame, in one plot

Tags: pandas, visualization, seaborn

I am creating probability distributions for each column of my data frame by distplot from seaborn library sns.distplot(). For one plot I do

```
x = df['A']
sns.distplot(x);
```

I am trying to use the FacetGrid & Map to have all plots for each columns at once
in this way. But doesn't work at all.

```
  g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col = 'A','B','C','D','E')
  g.map(sns.distplot())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to use `melt` to reshape your dataframe to long format, see this MVCE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,5)), columns = list('ABCDE'))
dfm = df.melt(var_name='columns')
g = sns.FacetGrid(dfm, col='columns')
g = (g.map(sns.distplot, 'value'))
```

Output:
[image]

---

From seaborn 0.11.2 it is not recommended to use `FacetGrid` directly. Instead, use `sns.displot` for figure-level plots.

```py
np.random.seed(2022)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,5)), columns = list('ABCDE'))
dfm = df.melt(var_name='columns')

g = sns.displot(data=dfm, x='value', col='columns', col_wrap=3, common_norm=False, kde=True, stat='density')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're getting this wrong on two levels.

- Python syntax.
  `FacetGrid(df, col = 'A','B','C','D','E')` is invalid, because `col` gets set to `A` and the remaining characters are interpreted as further arguments. But since they are not named, this is invalid python syntax.
- Seaborn concepts.

  - Seaborn expects a single column name as input for the `col` or `row` argument. This means that the dataframe needs to be in a format that has one column which determines to which column or row the respective datum belongs.
  - You do not call the function to be used by map. The idea is of course that `map` itself calls it.

Solutions:

- Loop over columns:

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import seaborn as sns

  df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(14,5), columns=list("ABCDE"))

  fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=5)
  for ax, col in zip(axes, df.columns):
      sns.distplot(df[col], ax=ax)

  plt.show()
  ```
- Melt dataframe

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import seaborn as sns

  df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(14,5), columns=list("ABCDE"))

  g = sns.FacetGrid(df.melt(), col="variable")
  g.map(sns.distplot, "value")

  plt.show()
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
# listing dataframes types
list(set(df.dtypes.tolist()))
# include only float and integer
df_num = df.select_dtypes(include = ['float64', 'int64'])
# display what has been selected
df_num.head()
# plot
df_num.hist(figsize=(16, 20), bins=50, xlabelsize=8, ylabelsize=8);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest approach is to just loop the columns and create a plot.

```
import numpy as np
improt pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,5)), columns = list('ABCDE'))
for col in df.columns:
    hist = df[col].hist(bins=10)
    print("Plotting for column {}".format(col))
    plt.show()
```