# Multiple distplots from pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to use Seaborn to plot the contents for a Pandas DataFrame, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to stack the distplots. The DataFrame I have looks something like this (simplified).

```
Image    | Obj1 | Obj2 | ... | ObjN
-----------------------------------
img1.jpg |   2  |   1  | ... | 0
-----------------------------------
img2.jpg |   5  |   5  | ... |  5
-----------------------------------
img3.jpg |   9  |   0  | ... |  1
```

Now, what I want to do is plot the distribution of the N-objects over the whole image set. With that I want to see how many images have Obj1 in them, how many have Obj2 int them, etc. It's a purely visual thing so don't think about how this might not be the best way to show said data.

In essence, what i want to do is something like:

```
for column in df.column:
   sns.distplot(column) # Stack these distributions together with different colors 

plt.show() # Display one plot with N-distribution plots inside
```

Wishing for an output similar to this (ish): [Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GtXL.png)

---

### EDIT

Building on @con_u's answer I've generated the following plots:

[No Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GtXL.png)
[Zoomed In on the Origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gqe1.png)

They are rather useless though with the vertical bars that can be seen in image 1. I know the distribution is heavily skewed towards the lower numbers (counts), so maybe I'm out of luck and need to reconsider my plotting options.

Comment: Seems like this question has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899463/how-can-i-overlay-two-graphs-in-seaborn. Will that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks @HielkeWalinga, but sadly this does not work in my case.

Comment: Maybe try some log scaling on one of axis? Can you provide code so we can reproduce your results?

Comment: Sadly I cannot, due to limitations. Log scaling would definitely be a good idea and would fix the horizontal scaling, yet it doesn't solve the problem with the bars still showing up. I'll tweak it a bit and see how I do. Thanks

Comment: Those bars seem to be coming from the `rug=True`. You can change that to `rug=False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Import library
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import random

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create an artificial dataframe
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
df = pd.DataFrame({'image':np.arange(100) + 1,
                  'obj1':np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=100),
                  'obj2':np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=100),
                  'obj3':np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=100),
                  'obj4':np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=100)})

df = df.set_index('image')
df.head(10)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Plot the distributions (column-wise) (if you just want some columns)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
sns.distplot(df[['obj1']], hist=False, rug=True)
sns.distplot(df[['obj2']], hist=False, rug=True)
sns.distplot(df[['obj3']], hist=False, rug=True)
sns.distplot(df[['obj4']], hist=False, rug=True)
sns.plt.show()

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Plot the distributions (column-wise) (looping method)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
for col in df.columns:
  sns.distplot(df[[col]], hist=False, rug=True)
```

You may also want to check the relevant ones here:

- [python: distplot with multiple distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045750/python-distplot-with-multiple-distributions)
- [Distribution probabilities for each column data frame, in one plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952133/distribution-probabilities-for-each-column-data-frame-in-one-plot)
- [Visualization with Seaborn](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.14-visualization-with-seaborn.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is similar to how I tried it initially (except I forgot the double brackets for reffing the columns). However I end up with pretty ugly plots that way. I've added images of the plots in the initial question (due to comment limitations).